# \textup in latex jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

I am trying to add a latex formula to my jupyter notebook. I was able to add all the formula but when when i added text with `$$\textup(This is my text)$$` i get:

[image]

But i was expecting [image]

Does jupyter not recognize \textup or is there something i have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to use curly brackets, like `$\textup{This is my text}$`. In this case i get [image].